# create a button that dosen't change its value when reload the page

Tags: php, jquery

```
`$(document).ready(function () {
        var state;
        var a = 0;
        $('button').click(function () {
            if (a == 0) {
                a = 1;
                $.cookie('active', 'active', {expires: 7});
                state=$('button').text($.cookie('active'));
            } else {
                a = 0;
                $.cookie('deactive', 'deactive', {expires: 7});
                state=$('button').text($.cookie('deactive'));
            }
        });
    });`
```

> `Blockquote`

I created a **button** when I click on it changes to `on` or `off`.

Defaultly,**button** is `off` : I want to remain `on` when reload the page.

Please explain with an example.

Comment: HTML is stateless. This means that when the page is next loaded your changes will be lost and the button will revert to its default state. You need to store the state of the button somewhere (localStorage, sessionStorage, cookie, server session, server database...) and then load then state when the page loads. There are *lots* of tutorials about this already if you take the time to research properly.

Comment: 1/ What is your current code? 2/ What did you tried? 3/ What doesn't works?

Answer (score 1):

You will do like this.

```
<button onclick="savestate()" type="button" value="off" id="Save">Save</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('Save').value= localStorage.getItem("btnvalue");}

function savestate(){ 
var input = document.getElementById("Save"); 
if(input.value == 'off')
{
localStorage.setItem("btnvalue", 'on');
}

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will store the button state in session or localstorage with true and false and check on the button on and off according to your session or localstorage value.

Comment: Please give an example

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the state of the button on or off to somewhere like database, cookies, or sessions. Then take the stored value and set it to default.